# Airflow: is it possible to embed a custom trigger in the DAG file?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Is it possible to embed a custom operator with a custom trigger in the DAG file? I tried something like this in Google Cloud Composer

`my_dag.py`:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.triggers.base import BaseTrigger, TriggerEvent
from airflow.utils.context import Context
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

from datetime import datetime

import os


class MyTrigger(BaseTrigger):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = path

    def serialize(self):
        return ("my_dag.MyTrigger", {"path": self.path})

    async def run(self):
        print("MyTrigger.run")
        exists = os.path.exists(self.path)
        yield TriggerEvent(exists)


class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    def __init__(self, path, deferrable, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = path
        self.deferrable = deferrable

    def execute(self, context: Context) -> None:
        print("MyOperator.execute: before deferring")
        if self.deferrable:
            self.defer(
                trigger=MyTrigger(path=self.path),
                method_name="execute_complete",
            )
        else:
          print("deferrable=False")
        print("MyOperator.execute: after deferring")

    def execute_complete(self, context: Context, event: dict) -> None:
        print(f"MyOperator.execute_compute: {dict}")
        return


dag = DAG('my_dag', description='Example', schedule_interval='@once', start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 17))

my_operator = MyOperator(task_id='my_task', path="/home/airflow/composer_kube_config", deferrable=True, dag=dag)

my_operator
```

The custom operator seemed okay, but the custom trigger failed with

```
Trigger failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/triggerer_job_runner.py", line 687, in update_triggers
    trigger_class = self.get_trigger_by_classpath(new_trigger_orm.classpath)

  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/triggerer_job_runner.py", line 728, in get_trigger_by_classpath
    self.trigger_cache[classpath] = import_string(classpath)

  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 36, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)

  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_dag'
```

It seems that Airflow failed to load the trigger.

Comment: I have the same issue. We use packaged dags (zip files) and it seems that the dags folder is not synchronized with the triggerer. That means you would need to create your custom Pypi package and install it in your Airflow environment every time you update the code.... `Because the DAGs folder is not synchronized with the Airflow triggerer, the inlined trigger code is missing when the trigger is executed.` https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/troubleshooting-triggerer#trigger_class_not_found

Comment: I have opened a github issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/36510

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because `my_dag.MyTrigger` in the trigger serialize is not a valid Python module path. Perhaps you can create a Python package in your DAG folder and use it. Also, update the trigger class path in the serialize accordingly
.

Example:

```
dag_folder
   - my_trigger
       - __init__.py
       - my_trigger.py
   - my_dag.py
```

in serialize class param will something like `dag_folder.my_trigger.my_trigger.MyTrigger`

**EDIT-1**

your dag folder needs to be synchronised with the Airflow trigger too then only above suggest solution will work.

Comment: Even if it is a valid package it will not work. I have the same issue in Cloud Composer and I have given up. If I want to create my own trigger package, I need to install it in the Cloud Composer environment from Pypi which means a restart of the production environment with each release. This is not suitable for us. `Because the DAGs folder is not synchronized with the Airflow triggerer, the inlined trigger code is missing when the trigger is executed`https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/troubleshooting-triggerer#trigger_class_not_found

Comment: right,  your dag folder needs to be synchronised with the trigger too